# Configure firewalld to distinguish home and public ethernet connection

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, firewall, firewalld

I connect my notebook via ethernet at home and outside. I want to open some ports for services like samba only at home and not somewhere else.

How can i let firewalld automatically detect where i am, so the correct zone will be set?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but hopefully a clue: Firewalld gets its connection information from NetworkManager, so it's really NetworkManager that you want to have make the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to System Settings (GNOME Settings): Network.
2. Click History to see your known WiFi networks
3. Configure one of your networks and click Security

From here you can assign a firewall zone. The default `drop` zone should be fine on untrusted networks while the `trusted` zone … you get the idea.

When you open services add it to the trusted zone (append `--zone="trusted"` to your commands) instead of the default zone.

Comment: I believe this answer only applies to WiFi connections, but the question was, I think, about wired ethernet connections (which appear as a single connection in Networkmanager, regardless of where you are connected).